# Getting error while communicating django channel with Redis

Tags: django, redis, django-channels

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmqzR.png)

I am trying to crate a chatapp.I referred to django tutorial provided in documentation.How to get rid of this error??

Comment: Do you have redis server installed?

Comment: looks like redis is not running on the port that channels is expecting. check its running. Also for async server development (and very much production) you should be using a posix OS windows has way to many limitations with python and async to be a stable production env.

Comment: I have installed it using docker image

Answer (score 0):

This error shows when the server is not started. Try double click on the .exe file and it would start your redis service. After that again try to connect to the redis.

Comment: But I installed using docker image...and docker server is running already.